# Using multiple ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

Starting a new thread... about same question.. I have tried all I am getting from different post and forums... none of the working for me..

What I want to do is...

```
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerA animated:YES];//Working fine
//Inside viewControllerA call viewControllerB
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerB animated:YES];//Working fine
//Dismiss both the Controllers. and present View
```

C

I tried.

1. Dismissing viewControllerA before presenting ViewControllerB // which directly going to view C
2. Dismissing viewControllerA in viewControllerB // No results.
   //DismissViewController should dismiss all stack.. but not working for me so I tried
3. Dismissing both viewContrller in viewControllerB //still it shows viewContrllerA

OMG...it's confusing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did.. not a good solution but works for now.. :)

///ViewDidLoad
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerA animated:YES];//Working fine

//inside ViewController A
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

//ViewWillAppear
[self presentModalViewController:ViewControllerB animated:YES];//Working fine

//inside ViewController B
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

Your code is unclear (you're using `self` twice when they probably refer to different things). I'm assuming what you want to do is (effectively) this:

```
[viewController presentModalViewController:viewControllerA animated:YES];
// time passes...
[viewControllerA presentModalViewController:viewControllerB animated:YES];
// time passes
... do something to dismiss both controllers ...
```

You might have luck with something like this:

```
[viewControllerA dismissModalViewController:NO];
[viewController dismissModalViewController:NO];
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "in" or "inside"; it doesn't matter what class you're "in". But generally, a view controller is responsible for its children. Typically, the parent sets itself as the delegate of the child. When the child is "done", it sends a message to the parent; the parent is responsible for dismissing the child. UIKit's prepackaged view controllers (UIImagePickerController/MFMailComposeViewController/MFMessageComposeViewController) all follow this pattern.

Comment: if I use viewController instead of self to presentModalViewController... it's not presenting view... here is how I am creating viewControllerA..... ViewControllerA *viewControllerA = [[[ViewControllerA alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: I'm using viewController to refer to whichever "root" view controller you're using. "self" is meaningless by itself. Sigh.

Comment: When you are saying use viewController instead of self... if I have to present view from current view controller... then I should use self right ??

Comment: Hey it's working not exactly a solution.. but.. I am calling Dismiss viewControllerA before Presenting B... Thanks for help.. I will vote you up.

Comment: What do you mean by "current" - the one that is being displayed, or the receiver of methods your executing? "self" is the latter.